# How to construct ExtJS4 layout

Tags: layout, extjs

Can't program quite not complicated structure so be so kind as to prompt me how can I solve this problem. I have tabPanel and on the first tab I want to place three panels but in specific order:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axspv.jpg)

Panel 0 (layout vbox) consist of Panel 1, 2 and 3 each are constructed with form fields and one grid. This is working properly. But when I try to add Panel 4 I receive empty tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your image the Panel 0 should use layout 'hbox' in my understanding.
I didn't worked with ExtJS 4, so I don't know the layouting mechanism, but what I saw is that the elements in my fiddle disappear when I remove the flex property.

Possibly the following fiddle is what you want:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cog

Comment: What can I say, just THANK YOU VERY MUCH, it's workong.